# Restlet multi Filter implementation

Tags: java, restlet

I have several `Resource` classes which some have **Filters** of their own (`LoginResource`, `ForceLogoutResource`) and some do not (`LogoutResource`).

```
    LoginFilter loginProcess = new LoginFilter();
    loginProcess.setNext(LoginResource.class);

    LogoutFilter forceLogoutProcess = new LogoutFilter();
    forceLogoutProcess.setNext(ForceLogoutResource.class);

    Router router = (Router)super.createInboundRoot();
    router.attach("/logout/{token}", LogoutResource.class); 

    router.attach("/logout", forceLogoutProcess);
    router.attach("/login", loginProcess);
```

I would like to add to this structure another Filter (`InputRequestFilter` that will validate input for all requests).

The routing ultimately should look like this:

```
request -> InputRequestFilter -> LogoutResource

request -> InputRequestFilter -> loginProcess 

request -> InputRequestFilter -> forceLogoutProcess
```

My questions are:

1. Should `InputRequestFilter` be `Filter` or of other type?
2. How exactly do I build the routing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a filter in front of all requests, we can do the following:

```
Router router = new Router(getContext());

InputRequestFilter inputRequestFilter = new InputRequestFilter(getContext());
inputRequestFilter.setNext(router);
return inputRequestFilter;
```

The method `setNext` accepts any Restlet (router, filter, resource, class that extends directly class Restlet, guard, ...).

I don't know what you want to implement in the new filter but it seems to be the correct approach.

We can also notice that you can also make more advanced routing configuration by leveraging the matching mode, as described below:

```
Router subRouter = new Router(getContext());
(...)

// something to attach (sub router, ...
router.attach("/path/{pathvariable}", subRouter)
      .setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
```

When using this feature, be careful since the path variables of sub router are only available within elements attached to the sub router.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you set a matcher for "starts with", isn't EQUALS_TO sufficient?

Comment: It's just to notify you that it's a way to attach preprocessing on a subset of elements. In your case, I think that a matching mode equals is enough ;-)